# Retrieving the total sum of a table item from a GROUP BY query

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have three tables

```
private static final String DTReasonTable = "create table tb_DTReasons(DTReasonId integer primary key autoincrement,DTReason text)";

private static final String ConfigurationTable = "create table tb_Config(ConfigId integer primary key autoincrement," +
        "RawMaterialName text,OutPut_pdt text,TotalWorkHrs real,Quantity real,ProcessStartTime real,OutputQuantity real,procesEndTime real)";

private static final String DownTimeTable = "create table tb_DownTimeTable(DT_Id integer primary key autoincrement,ConfigId integer," +
        "StartTime real,EndTime real,DTReasonId integer)";
```

I want to create a report like below

[image]

Can anyone help me to write a procedure for corresponding report generation?

```
  public Cursor getDtAnalysisReport()
{
    return this.data.rawQuery("select EndTime-StartTime as duration,tb_DTReasons.DTReason,count(tb_DownTimeTable.DTReasonId) from tb_DownTimeTable" +
            " inner join tb_DTReasons on tb_DownTimeTable.DTReasonId = tb_DTReasons.DTReasonId group by tb_DownTimeTable.DTReasonId ", null);

}
```

This is what I tried but I'm getting an error. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: `http://sqlfiddle.com` for putting schema with results

Comment: Please paste you desired report as screenshot is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DTReason AS 'Down Time Reason',
       SUM(EndTime - StartTime) AS 'Duration',
       SUM(EndTime - StartTime) /
       (SELECT SUM(EndTime - StartTime)
        FROM tb_DownTimeTable
       ) * 100 AS '% Total Down Time',
       COUNT(*) AS 'No of Occurrences'
FROM tb_DTReasons
JOIN tb_DownTimeTable ON tb_DTReasons.DTReasonId = tb_DownTimeTable.DTReasonId
GROUP BY tb_DTReasons.DTReasonId
```